# Which one will undergo sn2 most easily?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[!well i thought that sterically least hindered compound will undergo sn2 most easily but in this case it the compound having benzene ring is undergoing sn2 more easily although it will repel the attacking nucleophile due to its electron dense nature.why isnt that happening here??][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28e4y.jpg[image]

Comment: @Anket Aulakh Check this link: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48872/how-are-sn2-transition-states-stabilised-by-adjacent-double-bonds-and-carbonyl-g

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87827/why-are-alpha-carbonyl-halides-most-reactive-towards-sn2-reactions